# Which communities accept sheitels (wigs) as adequate hair coverings for married women?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, hair, hair-covering

Assuming that married women need to cover their hair today (I'm not going into that discussion), which communities accept that a sheitel is considered a covering?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm making this a community wiki, so please fill in as you can.

Are there communities that will wear synthetic but not human-hair?

You'll hear plenty of rabbis saying "a sheitel is no good if it looks too attracting", but that's subjective.  I'm looking for yes or no, does a wig count as covering.

You'll also hear of rabbis who paskened they don't count, but often the community practice is otherwise.

- American and Israeli yeshivish communities -- sheitels are the norm.
- Yekkes, old-school or yeshivish -- sheitels are fine.
- Chabad-Lubavitch -- I'd seen the quote from the Rebbe zt'l that sheitels are a good option ("kerchiefs can suddenly disappear into a pocket if you feel embarrassed"); is this both synthetic and human?
- Israeli Dati-Leumi and Charedi Dati-Leumi -- sheitels aren't the norm; is that a halachic thing or a practical/sociological one?
- American MO machmir -- accepted, if not loved.
- Hassidic, non-chabad (חג״ת) -- was it the Belzer Rebbe who said sheitels don't count?  Is that still Belz custom?  Do other Hassidic communities all accept sheitels?
- Satmar -- encouraged.

I know R' Ovadiah Yosef shlit'a says sheitels don't count; which non-Ashkenazic communities follow his psak?

- Syrians?
- Persians?  (And Bukharians as well I assume?)
- Spanish-Portuguese?
- North Africans?
- Others?

Comment: Reb Ovadiah ussaly poskins for everyone one but here in America alot of syrians follow Rav abba Shaul who allows it

Comment: never saw a source of any sefardic rav permiting it, you will need to be more specific and tell me where harav aba shaul permits it

Comment: He permitted it at least in his community. I know relatives of his who wear sheitels and they are bnos Torah, wives of B'nei Torah.

Comment: didn't mean geographically I mean where he wrote it

Comment: In Chabad-Lubavitch, the Rebbe strongly insisted that only Sheitels should be worn in public. Either synthetic or human hair are used, although human hair seems to be more fashionable. Many Lubavitch married women will wear tichels inside the home.

Answer (score -2):

All Ashkenazim outside of Chassidim.There is also a Chassidic custom that a Hat and a wig are required.

Comment: It's not just "all chassidim say no", is it?

Comment: no your question was "accept that a sheitel is considered a covering"
Lubavitch for example is the strongest Advocates for Shaitels I know

Comment: I heard from Rav Elyashiv's own mouth (recording) that the current shaitels that really look like beautiful real hair should not be permitted. he is pretty Ashkenazic and not Chassidish.

Comment: Right he accepts wigs Just not all of them.

Comment: Truth be told that he did not use the word "current". I just assumed that because of the extreme implications a literal understanding of Rav Elyashiv's statement would have on the entire Litvishe Ashkenazic world and the fact that no one is rushing to indiscriminately forbid all sheitels based on his statement.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong,but I think he stills hold they are Avodah Zarah and hence still Assur today?

Comment: If he does, it is only the Indian ones. I have a hard time believing he holds so since it has been determined that the hair is not takroves of Avodah Zara. It may be shorn in honor of the AZ but that does not fit the bill of what AZ is. See http://www.seforimonline.org/seforimdb/pdf/176.pdf

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Many Chassidim wear Sheitel and a Kercheif or Sheitel and a Snood.

The Lubavitcher Rebbe says Sheitel only as the second covering could be possibly "Ayin Hara"

Comment: @mochinrechavim Ayin Hara or Maaras Ayin? Also, do you have a source?