# Sheitels or no sheitels - where is the halacha?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

With very well respected Rabbis such as Rav Ovadia Yossef clearly stating that wigs (sheitels) are simply assur (forbidden) according to most poskim, while some other very well respected rabbis such as the Lubavitcher Rebbe encouraged wearing them. What are sources that each use to make their claim?

Comment: Related: [Which communities accept sheitels (wigs) as adequate hair coverings for married women?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/which-communities-accept-sheitels-wigs-as-adequate-hair-coverings-for-married)

Comment: By "where is the simple halacha?" are you looking for a single source that will mediate between Rav Ovadia and the Rebbe or a quotation from one of them coming down clearly on one side of the issue?

Comment: Maybe sources that each use to make their claim? Does the shulchan aruch mention this at all?

Comment: I heard that HaRav Bension Aba Shaul and HaRav Mordechai Eliyahu both permitted the Sheitels. However, Harav Elyashiv Shalit"a seems to be Oser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One source is Shabbos (64b), that is interpreted by some as allowing married women to cover their hair with only a wig in public (e.g. this is the interpretation of the Shiltei Giborim). R' Noach Chaim Tzvi Berlin disagrees and holds that this is not considered a legitimate headcovering (Atzei Arazim, Even HaEzer 21:2). Some other opinions hold that the problem is *mar'is ha'ayin* (Tiferes Yisrael), particularly if it is not an area where wigs are customary (Mishnah B'rurah, 75:15). The Magen Giborim holds that the only issur with wigs is if the woman is wearing a wig made from her own hair.

Part of R' Ovadia Yosef's opinion derives from the fact that Sefardi women historically followed the stricter opinion and did not wear wigs. R' Moshe Feinstein paskened that the lenient opinion is in the majority, and that there is no problem of *mar'is ha'ayin*, especially in communities where wigs are common (Igros Moshe, Even HaEzer 2:12).

Comment: excellent,I would just add that the Pri Migadim held using their own hair is mutar brought down by the same mishna brura you qouted.

Comment: @sam [Correct](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/38378).