# Can a Sheitel be made out of one's own hair?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

Suppose a married woman is able to create a [Sheitel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheitel) that is entirely made up of her own hair (detached, of course). Does that satisfy the requirement for covering her hair?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a matter of disagreement among the *poskim*. Those who say this is an acceptable type of hair covering include *Shiltei Giborim* ([*Shabbos* 29a](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&st=&pgnum=607) in *dapei haRif*) and *P'ri M'gadim* (*Eshel Avraham* OC 75:5).

Those who say it is unacceptable, and differentiate between a regular wig and a wig made out of a woman's own hair, include *Ateres Z'keinim* ([OC 75:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=312)), *Be'er Heiteiv* (OC 75:8, quoting *Ateres Z'keinim*), and *Magein Giborim* ([75:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19326&st=&pgnum=43)).

[CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a practical ruling.

Comment: The debate is whether that's called "pe'ah nochrit" -- *foreign* hair. For those who say it has to be foreign to you, I heard a legend about two identical twins who traded hair for their sheitels! (Personally? Eww....)

Comment: @shalom, I know twins who did it.

Comment: @Shalom Correct, this is based on the *mishna* in *Shabbos* (64b, יוצאה אשה... ובפאה נכרית). Interesting about the twins.

Comment: @Yishai they're likely the ones I heard about via a friend of a friend

Answer (score 5):

[Mishna Berura](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=%D7%A4%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99&pgnum=213&hilite=) (סימן עה, ס' ג, ס'ק טו):

> וכתב הפמ"ג דבמדינות שיוצאין הנשים בפיאה נכרית מגולה יש להם לסמוך על
>   השו"ע ומשמע מיניה שם דאפילו שער של עצמה שנחתך ואח"כ חברה לראשה ג"כ יש
>   להקל ובספר מגן גבורים החמיר בזה עי"ש.‏
>
> The Peri Megadim writes that in those countries were women wear wigs,
>   they can rely on the Shulchan Aruch. One can infer from this, that
>   even one's own hair that was cut off, and then later reattached, one
>   can be lenient (and this counts as a hair-covering). The Magen Giborim
>   was strict in this matter.

(*free translation; text copied from [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.75?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)*)

Answer (score 0):

I heard that it is okay.
Because once it is no longer attached to your head it is no longer considered your hair.