# Is there an authentic source for such a partial hair covering for women?

Tags: halacha, tznius-modesty, hair-covering

I'm aware that per 'Iqar HaDin (baseline Halakhah), Qitzur Shulhhan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef  [writes](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_82.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%9B%D7%90B-B%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%97%D7%A7B%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%91) that a woman may reveal two finger-breadths of her hair (where her hair connects to her head) while covering her hair.

Nevertheless, I see many women in Israel partially uncovering their hair in the fashion below. Is there an authentic tradition/source for such a covering?

[image: a woman with a hat on her head, with hair coming out the bottom of the hat both down the back of her head and her neck and a little at her temple]

[image: another woman with a hat on her head, with hair coming out the bottom of the hat both down the back of her head and her neck and a little at her temple]

Comment: Igrot Moshe is clear that those women are fulfilling all biblical requirements. As for Dat Yehudit, we know that depends on custom http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35908/759

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these aren't falls (i.e. half wigs), they would match up with the way the שלטי גיבורים, a commentary on the Ran, explains hair-covering in [Shabbat 64b](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&st=&pgnum=607) as I wrote [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/54000/501).

> [image: דשער באשה ערוה דאמרינן לא הוי אלא בשער הדבוק לבשרה ממש ונראה גם בשרה עם השיער אבל שיער המכסה שערה אין כאן משום שער באשה ערוה וגם לא משום פריעת ראש]

And again in his conclusion:

> [image: ובדברי הרא״ש תמצא דאין איסור בשער אשה משום ערוה אלא במחובר לבשרה וגם שהבשר נראה עם השיער כדאוקימנא]

Comment: Respectfully, his commentary could just as legitimately be understood to mean that the [hats many Haredi women wear today on top of their Sheitels](http://www.visithasidim.com/uploads/2/4/4/0/24401728/799199.jpg?130) are what he deems unnecessary (and that the Sheitel alone is sufficient).

Comment: @Lee, I see why you're saying that based on my snippets, but if you read the entire thing - at http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37953&st=&pgnum=607 you will see that he's defining what is considered hair that needs to be covered.

Answer (score 5):

You mean that the *head* is covered, but the hair hanging down beneath it is visible.

There is some room for discussion about this. The biblical source for hair-covering is the Sotah, and it says "the Kohen shall uncover the woman's *head*" (not "her hair.")

[Rabbi Yehuda Herzl Henkin thus writes](http://freepdfhosting.com/3637dbd864.pdf) in *Tradition* 37:3:

> Nevertheless, R. Feinstein could permit more than a tefah outside
>   the hairline simply by following his own line of reasoning. Since the
>   Torah specifies uncovering the sota’s head and not her hair, the kohen
>   needed to uncover only the hair on the woman’s head, and not what
>   hung down on her neck and shoulders. Consequently, no Torah obligation can be derived for a married woman to cover hair outside her hair-
>   line.

See Rabbi Henkin's article for much more on the subject.

I'm not saying it's permissible, but there is certainly room for discussion about it.