# Is beauty that is described in the Torah objective beauty?

Tags: history, beauty

Perceptions of beauty have changed throughout time.  For example, in the times of the Talmud, R' Yochanan, who was described as being fat (Berachos 13b), is also described in the Talmud as being exceedingly beautiful (Berachos 20a, for example).  However, today obesity is generally considered to be unattractive.

Similarly, across different cultures beauty manifests differently (See [this slideshow](http://www.cosmopolitan.com/style-beauty/g3279/weird-beauty/) for some examples - disclaimer: contains photos which I did not peruse to verify modesty).

What I am wondering is if the people who are described in the Torah as beautiful ([Bereishis 29:17, for example](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/k/k0129.htm#17)) were beautiful according to their time and their culture, or if there was an objective nature to their beauty which was not subject to vicissitudes of time and place.

Comment: why cant a fat person have a beautiful face?

Comment: @ray I didn't say they couldn't, but I don't think anyone's beauty as identified in the Torah is limited to their face.

Comment: i think he had a tremendous radiance about him - he would literally shine as it says in berachos

Comment: Isn't physical beauty inherently subjective? Wouldn't the Torah objectively recognize spiritual beauty?

Comment: @ray Reish Lakish the bandit was attracted to that spiritual shine?

Comment: I don't know that R Yochanon was as obese as some people today.

Comment: @DoubleAA he was large enough to make sitting up to say shemah impractical

Comment: @Daniel More like uncomfortable.

Comment: R' Akiva Tatz addresses this issue beautifully in the shiur I attached below. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBpjlW1yvyM

Comment: As you might guess there were no photographs, so the later generations could not judge the beauty of their ancestors. The only claim that could theoretically prove your question is if somebody could claim: I saw Grandma Rivkah and she's just about average :) So your question is pretty much doomed :(

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara in Megillah 15a says:

> תנו רבנן ארבע נשים יפיפיות היו בעולם שרה (ואביגיל רחב) ואסתר ולמאן דאמר אסתר ירקרוקת היתה מפיק אסתר ומעייל ושתי
>
> The Rabbis taught: There were four beautiful women in the world - Sarah, Avigayil, Rachav, and Ester.  And according to the opinion that Ester was green, take out Ester and put in Vashti

Lest one say that the Baraisa is referring to spiritual beauty, note that Vashti is a candidate for the list, and she was no saint.

These women lived over a long span of time.  Sarah lived at around 2000 BCE, Avigayil lived at around 1000 BCE, Rachav lived around 1300 BCE, and Ester lived at around 500 BCE.

It is always possible that each of them were beautiful in their own generation, but it does seem to be ranking them, both from the non-chronological order, and from that which Vashti will only make the list if Ester is bumped off (i.e. it seems like it is only the top four).

It would seem from here that the beauty described in the Torah is mutable from generation to generation and culture to culture.  Otherwise, it could not be compared or ranked.

This doesn't explain how it could be so, but at least points to the fact that it is so.

Comment: See http://halakhah.com/bababathra/bababathra_58.html, which mentions Eve and Adam, and Jacob, too. Eve and Adam being beyond comparison to Sarah

Comment: Couldn't it be relative to time and place? meaning they had 10 beauty dollars in their generation, and in our generation, the most beautiful women *to us* only have 8 beauty dollars.

Comment: @BabySeal I saw the Chava vs. Sarah comparison (tos. in Megilla mentions it) but in a vacuum one could say that would be had Sarah lived during Chava's time or vice versa.

Comment: So beauty depends on time and place?

Comment: @BabySeal No.  But if I would have tried to bring proof to that from Chava, one could have responded that yes it does, and the statement about Chava vs. Sara was saying if they had been in the same time and place.  I was saying how you could have rejected the proof, not how I would explain it according to my assumptions.

Comment: I dunno, the source seems to be wholly inconclusive to me. Good source though for the topic :)

Comment: @BabySeal I thought beauty was measured in millihelens https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_humorous_units_of_measurement#Beauty:_Helen

Answer (score 1):

Kli Yakar on [Breishit 24:16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14020&st=&pgnum=294) mentions quoting from the Talmud, [Tractate Taanit 24.](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit_24a.13) saying; that the Rabbis stated that if a woman has beautiful eyes, nothing else needs to be physically checked, even if the rest of her is ugly.

There appears to be some support for the notion of checking the eyes as Le'ah eyes were described as "delicate", and compared to Rachel (taking p'shat, not midrashic explanations), this was considered detrimental.

Yoseph is the only male that the Torah describes as "beautiful of form". In Nevi'im (prophets) Saul's height is described and David is described as being rosy-cheeked. For some reason, Tana"ch seems to describe more about the physical appearance of men than women when describing their beauty.

In summary, the Torah does not indicate what others considered to be standards of physical beauty, and I don't think its purpose was to account for public opinion or thinking of that time or any time, for that matter.

What occurred in Tana"ch, with David and Saul may be a different matter. For example, [Rashi on Shmu'el I 9:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14258&st=&pgnum=69) in describing the reason the girls gave Sha'ul a long answer to a simple question of where he could find the "seer of G-d" is so that the girls could stare at Sha'uls beautiful figure. So, it seems that at least there, his height, and perhaps, other physical features were significant to at least young girls - not much different standards from today!

Answer (score 1):

[Song of Songs 1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3001.htm) describes both the male and the female in the book as beautiful.

[Song of songs 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et3004.htm) describes beautiful eyes, long flowing hair, a full mouth of white symmetric teeth, red lips, a beautiful voice, rosy round cheekbones, a long slender neck, and a symmetric, well-proportioned bosom as being beautiful in women.

[Song of Songs 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt3007.htm) adds round hips, an hourglass figure, and a beautiful forehead.

[Female physical attractiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_attractiveness#Female_physical_attractiveness) has ties to eyes both in shape and color, as well as full lips. A high forehead and cheekbones are preferred, as is long hair and lighter, redder skin complexion. Symmetric breasts are favored. and preferred waist-to-hip ratio averages less than one, in favor of wider hips.

[Song of Songs 5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et3005.htm) is much more figurative, but it seems to describe a pale but ruddy complexion, a glowing countenance with curling black hair, beautiful even eyes, a bearded jaw line, rosy lips, and a tall, well-dressed figure with a sturdy stance, for men.

[Male physical attractiveness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_attractiveness#Male_physical_attractiveness) has been found to depend on facial symmetry, masculine facial features such as the jaw line, height, and a healthy, dominant presence representing stability and high social status.

So we see biblical descriptions of beautiful people, which include attractive features that have stood the test of time.

**It seems from this that there is an objective beauty that can be implied by the adjective.**

Comment: Song of Songs 7:5 describes as beautiful a nose like a tower. I get the sense the descriptions are not meant to teach us about objective beauty, or any beauty for that matter.

Comment: So would you say Rachel's beauty was specifically defined by the qualifications that you have identified as being eternal, or objective?

Comment: @DoubleAA The intro to rash's explanation on Songs addresses that. You are right, but also wrong, because ain mikrah yotzei miydei pshuto.

Comment: @YEZ That doesn't follow. It doesn't follow from the existence of objectively beautiful characteristics that they are the only beautiful characteristics.

Comment: @YEZ I don't know. You asked about people in the Torah. Here are two people in the torah, who's features are still considered attractive, to a degree.

Comment: @BabySeal Does that rule even apply to Shir HaShirim? Would you say then that a tower-like nose is an objectively beautiful thing?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=407 Don't know if Rashi wrote it, but someone thinks so. Also, look at the girl in the article. Her nose looks like a tower, broad at the bottom and thin towards the top. I think that's beautiful. A pinnocio nose wouldn't be, but towers aren't horizontally-oriented, so that's not what comes to mind. I wouldn't necessarily choose a tower to describe a nose, though the more i think about it, the more appropriate it seems. I wouldn't choose doves for eyes either, though, or sheep for hair.

Comment: @DoubleAA HA rash totally agrees with you though, about the nose, he goes with face instead. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9754&st=&pgnum=454

Comment: @DoubleAA interestingly enough though, the verse describes the tower as 'looking toward damascus', which gives one the perspective of the tower from one side to the other, not from bottom to top. Much more nose like.

Comment: @DoubleAA It follows if this is supposed to answer my question.  I didn't ask "is there any beauty in the Torah which is objective." I asked if beauty in the Torah is objective - when the Torah calls someone beautiful, is that objectively true.  If someone wants to answer with this, then it only answers if they are assuming all beauty described in the Torah falls into these guidelines.  Otherwise, this is a single example which says nothing about the rule.

Comment: @BabySeal ^^^ Re "you asked about people in the Torah"

Comment: and re "ein mikra yotzei midei pshuto" that is not so obvious when discussing Shir HaShirim - many mefarshim explain that to be the pshat of R' Akiva's "Shir HaShirim kodesh kodoshim" - kodshe kodoshim do not have a chelek l'baalim, and shir hashirim has no "pshuto" it is entirely meant allegorically. ping @DoubleAA

Comment: @YEZ It doesn't follow as I explained above no matter what anyone intended it to do. Why should intent affect logic?

Comment: @YEZ I posted rashi's intro to shir hashirim, where he clearly acknowledges the simple meaning in a comment to DoubleAA. Should I link the last bit of Songs 1 where the man and the woman are called beautiful, so that the descriptions of their beauty have the desired context?

Comment: @YEZ I edited that in. the intent of this answer is to supply you with a source that describes beauty which, when compared to contemporary studies, is still beautiful. It certainly need not apply in all cases in the Torah, but I think that for Song of Songs it is a strong source that answers your question. If you and others strongly disagree, I can delete it, or community wiki it so others can improve upon it.

Comment: @DoubleAA It was a mima nafshach - either it doesn't answer the question or that was what he meant to imply. I asked to clarify which was correct.  What am I missing here?

Comment: @YEZ can you state plainly what you don't like about my answer? I''m confused about what exactly you think I need to improve.

Comment: @BabySeal I don't not like your answer - I liked it better as a comment, because I don't think it really answers my question.  I was asking if when the Torah describes someone as beautiful, that means they were objectively beautiful and would be considered as such in any time or place.  You have shown that there is such a thing as objective beauty, but that isn't indicative of any general rule in the Torah.

Comment: @YEZ gotcha, works for shir but not for everywhere.

Comment: Exceptional! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

physical human beauty has to do with proportion and symmetry.

as it says regarding abshalom "In all Israel there was not a man so highly praised for his handsome appearance as Absalom. From the top of his head to the sole of his foot there was no blemish in him." (samuel II 14:25)

and disproportion is also a kind of blemish.

but the real beauty of a human being is spiritual beauty which shines on a person's face due to his good traits and wisdom. 
the book shaarei kedusha (part 1 gate 3) refers to a person with bad character traits using the verse in proverbs 11:22 "Like a gold ring in a pig's snout is a beautiful woman who shows no discretion"

logically this seems to be universal it has to do with resembling God's traits and those are absolute.

Comment: What logic are you using to arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: well a girl with a two foot long nose is not going to look to good. things needs to be in correct proportion and with symmetry. this is why all animals Gd created display symmetry

Comment: What logic are you using to arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: well a girl with a two foot long nose is not going to look to good. things needs to be in correct proportion and with symmetry. this is why all animals Gd created display symmetry

Comment: So you aren't using any logic at all.

Comment: well a girl with a two foot long nose is not going to look to good. isnt this common sense?

Comment: Only if beauty is objective, which is what we are debating. You are assuming your conclusion.

Comment: i changed the answer to address your point